# (HackerRank Day 2: Operators) Problem with Constructor

Tags: java, c#

In this HackerRank challenge, I need to **find the total meal cost** by adding **tip_percent** which is **20%** of the meal_cost and **tax_percent**  which is **8%** of the meal_cost and the meal_cost being **$12**. So the output must be a round number of 15 but **my output comes out as $14.**

It does seem to work properly with custom values like $12.50 for meal_cost which later totaled comes out as a rounded value of $16. What am I doing wrong here?

```
static double findMealTotal(double meal_cost, int tip_percent, int tax_percent) {

    tip_percent = (int)(meal_cost * tip_percent)/100;
     tax_percent = (int)(meal_cost * tax_percent)/100;
      return meal_cost + tip_percent + tax_percent;
}

private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double meal_cost = scanner.nextDouble();
    int tip_percent = scanner.nextInt();
    int tax_percent = scanner.nextInt();

    //changed solve to mealTotal
    double mealTotal = findMealTotal(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent);

    System.out.println(Math.round(mealTotal));

    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: That, by the way, is not C#.  Why did you tag it with both `[java]` and `[c#]`

Comment: I want to do the challenge in C# as well and tagged it as well as both languages are very similar looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using integers. Integers are rounded, so you loose precision over the next calculation. Try using doubles and cast to int at the end.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double cost = findMealTotal(12, 20, 8);
        Console.WriteLine(cost.ToString());
    }

    static double findMealTotal(double meal_cost, int tip_percent, int tax_percent)
    {
        double tip = meal_cost * tip_percent / 100;
        double tax = meal_cost * tax_percent / 100;
        return meal_cost + tip + tax;
    }
```

And don't reuse parameters inside your function. It is bad practice.

Comment: It is worth noting that with double you might lose some precision as well. Some results like `12.3333336` instead of `12.3333333` are to be expected. You precision matter one should you `BigDecimal` (with constructor from String).

Comment: You shouldn't need `BigDecimal` to deal with the cost of a meal (unless you have a completely devalued currency).  Working with `decimal` is nearly always sufficient when working with money.  @asimrai: Consider using this code, but with `decimal` instead of `double`. (and use `decimal` for the percentages as well - that way you can work with my local tax percentage: 8.25%)

Comment: thanks for the tip guys I used decimal on C# and it worked perfectly.